# jQuery Datepicker how can I add an array of dates to beforeShowDay

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an jQuery Datepicker Calendar for tour bookings.
Some days of the week are not available for bookings but these blocked dates are depending on the month(season). So for instance in December every day is available except Sunday, November is not available at all and in April every Wednesday, Friday and Sunday are unavailable. This is working so far.

I now want to add an array of fixed dates which should be blocked aswell (for instance: 07.12.2013, 11.12.2013), but I'm struggling to get it work.

Here is my current code:

```
$("#tripDate").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: +2,
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "images/cal.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    beforeShowDay: function unavailable(date) {
        var year = date.getYear();
        var day = date.getDay();
        var month = date.getMonth();
        if (month == 10) {
            return [(day == 8)];
        } else if (month == 3 || month == 4 || month == 5 || month == 8 || month == 9) {
            return [(day != 3 && day != 5 && day != 0)];
        } else {
            return [(day != 0)];

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var array = ['07.12.2013', '11.12.2013'];
$("#tripDate").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: +2,
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "images/cal.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    beforeShowDay: function unavailable(date) {
        var f = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', date)
        var year = date.getYear();
        var day = date.getDay();
        var month = date.getMonth();
        if ($.inArray(f, array) > -1) {
            return [false];
        } else if (month == 10) {
            return [(day == 8)];
        } else if (month == 3 || month == 4 || month == 5 || month == 8 || month == 9) {
            return [(day != 3 && day != 5 && day != 0)];
        } else {
            return [(day != 0)];

        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5tBWh/)

Comment: Dear Arun, thank you for your advice - that was extremly quick!
Great - That worked perfect!!!

Comment: Is there a way to show the Enabled days and disabled days outside the calendar widget? I want to show all days for the next 7 days from tomorrow, and then set a color and text. Available days in green with the text "available" and unavailable days in red with "unavailable". Is this somehow possible? Thanks in advance ;)